# How to remove duplicate in linkedlist by retaining the order

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to understand how to remove the duplicates from LinkedList in java. I googled and found some answers but in some of the answers they have mentioned as Node. I am not getting from where this node is coming from as i don't see any method in LinkedList returning the value as 'Node'.

It would be great if any one help me to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the below link, this answers your question well:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-duplicates-from-a-sorted-linked-list/

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the linked list, adding each element to a hash table. When we discover a duplicate element, we remove the element and continue iterating. We can do this all in one pass since we are using a linked list.

The following solution takes O(n) time, n is the number of element in the linked list.

```
public static void deleteDups (LinkedList<Integer> list){
  HashMap<Integer, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
  Iterator<Integer> itr = list.iterator();
  while(itr.hasNext()){
      int nextNode = itr.next();
      if(map.containsKey(nextNode)){
          itr.remove();
      } else {
          map.put(nextNode, true);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks amansinghal for the response. I am not getting from where this LinkedListNode  comes from?

Comment: LinkListNode is just an abstract concept, basically we call the entries in the link list as nodes. I have updated the code so that it would be easier for you to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the node since this would expose the internals of the LinkedList. You can use an Iterator and iterate over the List; the iterator will keep track of the nodes and on the iterator you can call remove.